# namespaces and simplexml, not able to access xml-tag

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

I'm desperately trying to parse an xml-feed by using simpleXML and php. I googled a lot and it seems others have also raised that specific question but I found no answer, solution. Question is how can I access here the tag `<title>` or price. I am able to retrieve  `<realEstateId>` but struggling to get the information below

```
 <resultlist:realEstate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

like `<title>` .

The code I wrote looks like this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($res);
$namespaces = $xml->getNameSpaces()

foreach ($xml->resultlistEntries->resultlistEntry as $entry){
  echo  '<BR>realEstateId: '.$entry->realEstateId.'<br>';//Works!
          $resultlist = $entry->children($namespaces["resultlist"]);  
          $echo $resultlist->title;//NO RESULT
}
```

and this is the XML-structure. The complete Feed is here:http://v490.ncsrv.de/sdk-Immoscout/feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<resultlistEntries numberOfHits="1699" realEstateType="0">
    <resultlistEntry xlink:href="https://rest.immobilienscout24.de/restapi/api/search/v1.0/expose/87650970" id="87650970" modification="2016-03-29T22:38:06.000+02:00" creation="2016-03-29T22:37:58.000+02:00" publishDate="2016-03-29T22:37:58.000+02:00">
        <realEstateId>87650970</realEstateId>
        <resultlist:realEstate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="search:ApartmentRent" id="87650970">
            <title>ATTRAKTIVES   1  Z I M M E R  W O H N U N G</title>
            <address>
                <street>Mommsenstraße</street>
                <houseNumber>10</houseNumber>
                <postcode>10629</postcode>
                <city>Berlin</city>
                <quarter>Charlottenburg (Charlottenburg)</quarter>
                <wgs84Coordinate>
                    <latitude>52.503248198968045</latitude>
                    <longitude>13.316445663450631</longitude>
                </wgs84Coordinate>
                <preciseHouseNumber>true</preciseHouseNumber>
            </address>
            <companyWideCustomerId>001.2637750</companyWideCustomerId>
            <titlePicture xlink:href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig03/N/473/710/642/473710642-0.jpg/ORIG/resize/60x60%3E/extent/60x60/format/jpg/quality/50" id="87650970" modification="2016-03-29T23:27:30.015+02:00" creation="2016-03-29T23:27:30.015+02:00" publishDate="2016-03-29T23:27:30.015+02:00">
                <floorplan>false</floorplan>
                <titlePicture>true</titlePicture>
                <urls>
                    <url scale="SCALE_118x118" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig03/N/473/710/642/473710642-0.jpg/ORIG/resize/118x118%3E/extent/118x118/format/jpg/quality/50"/>
                    <url scale="SCALE_210x210" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig03/N/473/710/642/473710642-0.jpg/ORIG/resize/210x210%3E/format/jpg/quality/50"/>
                    <url scale="SCALE" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig03/N/473/710/642/473710642-0.jpg/ORIG/resize/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E/format/jpg/quality/50"/>
                    <url scale="SCALE_AND_CROP" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig03/N/473/710/642/473710642-0.jpg/ORIG/legacy_thumbnail/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%/format/jpg/quality/50"/>
                    <url scale="WHITE_FILLING" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig03/N/473/710/642/473710642-0.jpg/ORIG/resize/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E/extent/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%/format/jpg/quality/50"/>
                </urls>
            </titlePicture>
            <floorplan>false</floorplan>
            <streamingVideo>false</streamingVideo>
            <listingType>L</listingType>
            <privateOffer>false</privateOffer>
            <realtorLogo>https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig04/L/329/627/211/329627211-0.png</realtorLogo>
            <realtorLogoForResultList xsi:type="common:Picture" xlink:href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig04/L/329/627/211/329627211-0.png">
                <floorplan>false</floorplan>
                <titlePicture>false</titlePicture>
                <urls>
                    <url scale="SCALE" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig04/L/329/627/211/329627211-0.png/ORIG/resize/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E/quality/50"/>
                    <url scale="SCALE_AND_CROP" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig04/L/329/627/211/329627211-0.png/ORIG/legacy_thumbnail/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%/format/jpg/quality/50"/>
                    <url scale="WHITE_FILLING" href="https://pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net/pic/orig04/L/329/627/211/329627211-0.png/ORIG/resize/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E/extent/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%/format/jpg/quality/50"/>
                </urls>
            </realtorLogoForResultList>
            <price>
                <value>440.00</value>
                <currency>EUR</currency>
                <marketingType>RENT</marketingType>
                <priceIntervalType>MONTH</priceIntervalType>
            </price>
            <livingSpace>52.40</livingSpace>
            <numberOfRooms>1.0</numberOfRooms>
            <builtInKitchen>true</builtInKitchen>
            <balcony>false</balcony>
            <garden>false</garden>
            <calculatedPrice>
                <value>440.00</value>
                <currency>EUR</currency>
                <marketingType>BUDGET_RENT</marketingType>
                <priceIntervalType>MONTH</priceIntervalType>
                <rentScope>WARM_RENT</rentScope>
            </calculatedPrice>
        </resultlist:realEstate>
    </resultlistEntry>
```

Comment: What I've found with XML Libraries is that sometimes you have to cast the output to (String) when you want a string representation of the value.  `$resultlist = $entry->children((String) $namespaces["resultlist"]); `But again you're getting no output so perhaps my hint does not apply.

Comment: If you add a link to complete XML or post it in the question, maybe you can obtain better help. Above XML is not-parseable, so we cannot test-it.

Comment: thank you for looking at it. I have uploaded the complete response here: [link] http://v490.ncsrv.de/sdk-Immoscout/feed.xml  the string cast did not have any effect